# Discussion board/comment exchange around individual document in document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, sharepoint-addin, modern-experience, comments

I want to have a discussion functionality around each document stored in the SharePoint Online document library.

Users can exchange comments around each document and can see the interaction. It is similar to Discussion Board APP but the only difference is that the discussion needs to be around a single document. As with the discussion Board APP, too many discussions around different documents can confuse the users.

Could you please suggest any OOTB functionality or any other easy-to-implement idea?

Answer (score 0):

If your documents are office files, I suggest you use Office inline comments feature. To use it, users need to open the file, then they will find **Comment feature** like the below:
[image]
[image]
Besides, there is a blog listed other methods for your reference:
https://sharepointmaven.com/6-ways-to-add-comments-to-documents-in-sharepoint/